# openERP insert query

Tags: insert, odoo

i have this function (_def_init) to insert some values in table attributes  (field_one,boolean_field) but it couldn't affect the the table.

It would be great if you help me with it.

class test_code(osv.osv):

```
  _name="test.code"    
  _columns = {
        'field_one':fields.char('Field One'),

        'boolean_field':fields.boolean('Boolean Filed'),
}  

def _def_init(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    lst = ['A','B','C','D']
    for sk in lst:
        sql="""INSERT INTO test_code (field_one) VALUES(%s) """% sk
        cr.execute(sql)
    cr.commit()

    return True 

_defaults = {
             'boolean_field': _def_init,     
}
```

test_code()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenERP gurus say it is not a good policy to bypass the ORM. So, instead, why don't you try to use `self.pool.get('obj_name').create(cr, uid,values)` to insert values into your object?

It should be something like:

```
def _your_funcion(self, cr, uid, id_request, context=None):
    values = { 'field_one': 'Your_data_here' }
    self.pool.get('test.code').create(cr, uid,values)
    return True
```

Comment: I thank you for your concern and i know that it is not a good policy, but my question is why this is not working (the above function). it works for single value without iterating through the list.